# Obtener valor de un atributo de un objeto php

Tags: php, objeto, sintaxis

Tengo el siguiente objeto, el cual puedo ver con var_dump($cases):

```
object(stdClass)#1295 (2) {      
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["case.name"]=>
  string(3) "G20"
}
```

Para obtener por ejemplo el valor del atributo id, puedo leerlo asi:

```
$case->id;
```

Pero presento problemas si quiero obtener el atributo case.name, ya que el punto genera un error de sintaxis:

```
$case->case.name;
```

Lamentablemente no puedo cambiar el nombre del atributo como tal porque significaría un cambio muy grande en todo el código.

He intentado colocandolo entre comillas, pero sigue generando error de sintaxis, si alguien sabe cómo se puede hacer uso de ese atributo lo agradecería enormemente.

Comment: Intenta con `$case->{'case.name'}`

Comment: Esto solucionó mi problema, muchas gracias Juan